# How to change android activity in Eclipse cross-platform Libgdx project

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

Hi all I have question.

I want to use Scoreloop system in my LibGDX game. So i want to change Libgdx Android Activity to Scoreloop Activity. The problem is that Libgdx abstract layer is out of Android Eclipse project - Libgdx shares Eclipse desktop project and Android Eclipse project. The main game logic is out of Android Eclipse project.

Summing up - How is the simplest way to change android activity in cross-platform Libgdx eclipse project.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put android specific code at libgdx android project.

Take a look at http://decisiontreegames.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/writing-android-specific-code-in-libgdx/ for a better integration model.